# Scraping all pages on quote.toscrape with scrapy

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm trying to scrape some information on the website : http://quotes.toscrape.com/

But I cannot find a way to scrape all the pages, I just had the first pages for now.

Here's my script so far :

```
import scrapy

from ..items import QuotetutorialItem

class QuoteSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'quotes'
    start_urls = ['http://quotes.toscrape.com/']

    def parse(self, response):

        items = QuotetutorialItem()

        all_div_quotes = response.css('div.quote')

        for quotes in all_div_quotes:   

            title = quotes.css('span.text::text').extract()
            author = quotes.css('.author::text').extract()
            tags = quotes.css('.tag::text').extract()

            items['title'] = title
            items['author'] = author
            items['tags'] = tags

            yield items

        next_page = response.xpath('//*[@class="next"]/a/@href').extract_first()
        if next_page:
            yield scrapy.Request(
                response.urljoin(next_page),
                callback=self.parse
            )
```

I have also tried this :

```
next_page = response.xpath('//*[@class="next"]/a/@href').get()
absolute_next_page_url = response.urljoin(next_page)

if absolute_next_page_url is not None:
    yield scrapy.Request(absolute_next_page_url)
```

And this :

```
next_page = response.css('li.next a::attr(href)').get()


if next_page is not None:
    yield response.follow(next_page, callback = self.parse)
```

But none of these solutions seems to work.

ANy ideas ? :)

Thanks !

Comment: Are you sure your script doesn't work?  the xpath `'//*[@class="next"]/a/@href'` works for me?

Comment: Which one ? The first or the second ?

Comment: It works for you ? You had all the pages ? Whick line of code did you write in the terminal ?

Comment: `response.xpath('//*[@class="next"]/a/@href').extract_first()`

Comment: Which line of code did you write in the terminal ? Because with 'scrapy crawl quote it doesn't work for me.

Comment: I ran `scrapy shell  http://quotes.toscrape.com/`, (which opens an interactive shell with a response object), then ran `response.xpath('//*[@class="next"]/a/@href').extract_first() `